Convergence and meromorphic continuation of a Dirichlet series under RH
Consider a Dirichlet series $F(s) = \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}$ such that  $a_{n} = O(1)$. Suppose the Dirichlet series
$$\zeta(s)F(s)=\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{(a\star1)(n)}{n^{s}}$$
converges absolutely in the half-plane $\Re z > c>1/2$, with $c <1$ and has a meromorphic continuation to $\Re z \geq c $ with a single pole at $c$ of residue $\zeta(c)$.
Assuming the Riemann Hypothesis is true, can we say that $F(s)$ converges in the half-plane $\Re z > c$ and has a meromorphic continuation to $\Re z\geq c$  with a single pole at $c$ of residue $1$?

The condition $\mathrm{res}{s=c}\zeta(s)F(s)=\zeta(c)$ implies $\mathrm{res}{s=c}F(s)=1$, not $\mathrm{res}_{s=c}F(s)=1/\zeta(c)$. Consider updating your post.

If we assume absolute convergence of $\zeta(s)F(s)$, rather than just convergence, than the convergence of $F(s)$ follows.

I've updated the post. Thank you for catching this.

@GHfromMO  : How do we prove it?

I added a short proof of my claim.

Thank you, that's a perfect answer. I can now proceed. I will edit the query to include absolute convergence...

Per the OP's request, I prove that if the Dirichlet series of $\zeta(s)F(s)$ converges absolutely in the half-plane $\Re z > c>1/2$, and the Riemann hypothesis is true, then the Dirichlet series of $F(s)$ converges in the half-plane $\Re z > c>1/2$. To see this, let us abbreviate $b=a\star1$ so that $a=b\star\mu$. Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$\sum_{n\leq x}a(n)=\sum_{\ell\leq x}b(\ell)\sum_{m\leq x/\ell}\mu(m)\ll \sum_{\ell\leq x}|b(\ell)|(x/\ell)^{c+\varepsilon}\ll x^{c+\varepsilon}.$$
The result follows.
